# sysctl: /etc/security/limits.conf(55): invalid syntax, continuing

Tags: 16.04, configuration, ulimit

My `/etc/security/limits.conf` (55 & 56):

```
*               hard    nofile          65535
*               soft    nofile          8192
```

I am trying to:

```
sysctl -p --load /etc/security/limits.conf
```

And received this errors:

```
root@petersamokhin:~# sysctl -p --load /etc/security/limits.conf
sysctl: /etc/security/limits.conf(55): invalid syntax, continuing...
sysctl: /etc/security/limits.conf(56): invalid syntax, continuing...
```

I have just copypasted this lines from google. Why this error occured ? How to fix this? Thanks.

---

Also tried:

```
sysctl -p --load /etc/security/limits.conf
```

and tried to delete `# End of file`, tried to delete spaces, tried with sudo. No result.

Comment: Try this `sudo sysctl -p --load=/etc/security/limits.conf`

Comment: @George already tried. Same result

Comment: Please add `sudo`

Comment: ok I see the problem you have a syntax error in the file your loading!

Comment: @George with `sudo` same result too. This file was default. I only added this two lines in the end of file

Comment: ok let me look at mine

Comment: Move your entry below the line `# End of file`

Comment: Maybe funny EOL chars? `od -bc /etc/security/limits.conf`

Comment: @George removed line `# End of file` - not helps.

Comment: What do you get with `head -n 56 /etc/security/limits.conf | tail -n 2 | od -bc`?

Comment: @waltinator result of `head -n 56 /etc/security/limits.conf | tail -n 2 | od -bc` is on the screenshot: https://pp.userapi.com/c836320/v836320638/57303/qHRjxoDtU8k.jpg

Answer (score 1):

*limits.conf * is parsed by the PAM *pam_limits * module
at session startup - it doesn't use *sysctl.conf*  syntax.